# Process return (int), to another program

Tags: c#

Good afternoon,

I have a process (console), where the main it will return an integer.

I will start this process from another in this way:

```
Process processo = new Process();

processo.StartInfo.FileName = caminhoExecutavel;
processo.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized;
processo.Start();
```

How can I test this return (integer) the first process?

explanation:

I have a program (1) that will call an executable (2) as above.

Need to test this program (1) return (int) this executable (2). because the main it returns an integer.

I'm not able to find how / where can I get this return.

NOTE: Even by code within the program (1).

Answer (score 1):

If you wait for the process to exit, you can read the `ExitCode` property. See [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.exitcode.aspx).